# How to pop up to start destination (Compose Navigation)

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-architecture-navigation, android-jetpack-navigation

I'm using the Navigation Component for Jetpack Compose.

I'm having troubles in clearing my backstack to contain only the starting destination when I navigate.

For example, if I have 3 screens A, B, C and D with A being my start destination.

My navigation might look like:

A -> B -> A -> C

Let's say I wish to clear the back stack to A when I'm navigating from C to D.

This is what happens when I do:

```
navController.navigateToD {
    popUpTo(navController.navGraph.startDestinationId) {
        inclusive = false
    }
}
```

A -> B -> A -> D

My backstack will look like that because it matches the `startDestinationId` to A and therefore will pop up to the first A entry it finds and not to the root.

I've tried to use `popUpTo(navController.navGraph.id)` and that pops the whole backstack and doesn't leave the start destination in the stack.

Can anyone help me with trying to pop up to the start destination in this scenario?

Also can anyone help to explain the `backQueue` and what is `navGraph.id`? Because I'm finding the first element of `navController.backQueue` to not be my starting destination.

It also seems `destination.id` is not unique for each backstack entry but is unique for each destination instead?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, why do you have 2 screen A in your back stack.
A is your start destination and you navigated from A -> B.
From B you navigated to A and your back stack became A -> B -> A.
Instead of navigating to A from B. You should call `navController.popBackStack()` and your back stack will be just A instead of A -> B -> A.

Because you have 2 A in your back stack, when you navigate from C to D. You back stack is cleared up to the second A and become A -> B -> A -> D. I think this is the normal behavior. If your back stack had one A, it would work as you expected.

Secondly, if you want to clear the whole back stack just keep the startDestination when navigation to a screen you can call the below extension function.

```
fun NavHostController.navigateSingleTopToAndRetainState(route: String) = this.navigate(route) {
    popUpTo(
        this@navigateSingleTopToAndRetainState.graph.findStartDestination().id
    ) {
        saveState = true
    }
    launchSingleTop = true
    restoreState = true
}
```

Comment: So A, B and C are bottom tab navigation destinations. Currently they are set to have `singleTop = true`. So if you navigate from A tab, to B tab, and click on A tab, it probably makes sense not to pop the back stack.

Essentially A, B, C are things a user can navigate to whilst in the app. When they logout, they reach to D (sign in screen) and you ideally want their previous navigation history erased.

This is possible to do, but it can create issues with deeplinking.

Comment: Right now, A destination is my "home screen" and is my starting destination. But a user must be logged in. If user is not logged in, from A screen, go to D screen to sign in. When user signs in, pop back stack to pop D off, and return to A.

Ideally I keep the strategy of popping of D when user signs in, then they can return to their previous screen. This helps with deeplinks which can make some artificial backstack. So say you deeplink into B, stack should look like A -> B -> D (if you aren't logged in). Then you log in and pop D off to return to B.

Comment: Hmm, I did not know, you had such a use case. Now, we should find a way not to add the same route to back stack while navigating on the bottom tab bars.